# jQuery Limiting Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, automation

Is there a better way to stop people being able to select more checkboxes than this?

I'd like the script to be dynamic, depending on the class applied, which would always contain the max value allowed (for example "limit_1" or "limit_2").

Presently, I'm creating a function per class instance, but this seems like total overkill.

Is there a better way to take the number from the class and use this within the function for both checking and the alert?

```
$('.limit_1 input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('.limit_1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 1) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 1");
    }
});

$('.limit_2 input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('.limit_2 input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 2");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cleanup your code by first using the .siblings() method. In addition, you could add an HTML data-* attribute to the direct parents of checkboxes, the value of which is retrieved with your change event. With this approach, you can use a single event listener.

In addition, this will avoid having to define separate limit classes, which would likely require you to manipulate the class string where the limit is hardcoded. Dynamically defining and retrieving the limits through the data-* attribute is cleaner.

```
//Parent elements HTML for checkboxes

<div class="checkbox-container" data-limit="2">
   //Checkboxes with lower limit
</div>

<div class="checkbox-container" data-limit="3">
   //Checkboxes with higher limit
</div>


//JS
$('.checkbox-class').on('change', function(e) {
   var limit = parseInt($(this).parent().data("limit"));
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert("The limit is " + limit)
   }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbrodzik/vVxM2/2229/)

Comment: Nice work. I completely overlooked the simplicity of using a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach can be declaring a variable for example:

```
var i = 0;
```

whenever a user clicks on a checkbox, check if it is checked or unchecked, if it is checked

```
i++
```

otherwise

```
i--
```

this will help you to check if i == 2 ? if it is equal to 2 at any point, alert them 'not more than 2'. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

give them the same class to `limit_1, limit_2, ...` like `limitedChecked`

add event handler base on this class

```
    $('.limitedChecked input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        var limit = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(" ").find(element =>element.startsWith("limit_")).slice(-1);

        if ($('.limit_'+ limit +' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > limit) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            alert("allowed only " + limit);
        }
    })
```

then get `.limit_1` from class and get last char of this string

here's a working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ahdffa7/)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it actually...

```
$('.step input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0];
    if ($('.limit_'+num+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > num) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only "+num);
    };
});
```